# jQuery dialog is not showing

Tags: jquery

i Have written script like

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnClick").click(function () {
       $("#dialog").dialog('open');
       return false;
       });
    $("#dialog").dialog({
       autoOpen: false,
       width: 900,
       resizable: false,
       modal: true,
       title: "View Time Sheet",
       width: "500px"
       });
  });
```

But getting error like `"0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'"`. What is  the problem ? 
Please help me

Comment: When do you get that error/what browser are you using/could you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: are you calling `noConflict()` anywhere in your code.. or is there any other version jQuery/some other library like prototype or mootools included in your page

Comment: Please remove **width: "500px"**. Do not use px for width. You used twice the property width.

Comment: your code is working fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FpeLh/1/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not included the UI library of jQuery, you can add the jquery ui library after jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine on Jfiddle, kindly check whether the requisite libraries have been included or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is Getting error because of Adding jquery References morethan once. That's it.